# checkboxes when checked, delete checked messages

Tags: php, email

How to make that at the push of a button

```
"<input type ='submit' name='delete' value='Delete messages'>"
```

deleted messages selected by a checkbox? All messages and checkboxes appear through the counter "for" as messages are received. What im doing wrong? I think i have mistake with foreach and form action. Please, help me

my code is:

```
<php function display_list($auth_user, $accountid, $messageid, $fullheaders) {
if(!$accountid) {
    echo "<p style=\"padding-bottom: 100px\">No mailbox selected.</p>";
} else {
    $imap = open_mailbox($auth_user, $accountid);
    if($imap) {
        $headers = imap_headers($imap);
        $messages = count($headers); ?>

        <div class="view-mailbox-block">
            <div class="new-message">
                <form action="index.php?action=new-message" method="post">
                    <input type ='submit' value='Write a letter'>
                </form>
            </div>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type ='submit' name='delete' value='Delete messages'>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="incoming-sent-messages-mail">
                <p>Почта</p>
            </div>
            <div class="incoming-sent-messages">
                <div class="incoming-sent-messages-p">
                    <p>
                        <?php echo "<a href='index.php?action=view-mailbox'>"; ?> View </a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo "<a href='index.php?action=view-mailbox-sent'>"; ?> Sent </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="senders overflow">
                    <form class="sender-checkbxes">
            <?php echo '<input type="checkbox" name="deleteall" value="checkbox-all">'; ?>
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $messages; $i++) {
                echo "<div><div>";
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="<?php echo $delete ?>">';
                echo "</form>";
                echo "</div></div>\n";
            } ?>
            <form action='index.php?action=delete&messageid='<?php echo $check;?>'>
            <?php if(!empty($_POST['delete'])) {
                foreach($_POST['delete'] as $check) {
                    imap_delete($imap, $check);
                    imap_expunge($imap);
                    imap_close($imap);
                    return true;
                }
            } ?>
            </form>
                 </div>
```

Comment: `value="<?php echo $delete ?>`... What is the value of `$delete` here?

Comment: @Chukwuemeka Inya  i'have mistake here, instead $delete must be $check